# Сворачивания части кода в Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Пропала возможность свернуть часть кода в .html файлах в VS Code.
В .js все есть как и раньше

Вот пример с js файла
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот в html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто-то знает как вернуть эту возможность?

Comment: Плагин для html установлен?

Comment: А какой? Эта функция была с коробки, а пару дней назад просто пропала и все...